# Extracting response which is equal to the input value used in a search engine

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to record a search box that when you type a character a suggested words is being captured, and I wanted to select from the list of suggested words the exact word I used in the text box.

```
Input = pizza
output:
[{"option":"pizza guy"},{"option":"pizza"},{"option":"pizza recipe"},{"option":"pizza oven"}]
```

I wanted to select the exact word in my input parameter.

I tried using the regEx Extractor and JSon Extractor

```
Regex:
{"option":"(.+?)"},
$1$
1
[RegEx][1]


JSON Extractor
$..[?(@.option=='${p_input}')] <-- not returning anything
```

[JSon Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9iAW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON path should be

```
$[?(@.option == '${inputWord}')]
```

[image]

**Result**
I stored your Json string in variable `inputJson`
[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul Jadhav - thanks for the response.
However, I wanted to select the same word I key in the search box. if it's Match No = 0 then it will randomly select from the list. 

Is there a way to capture the Input Parameter?

Comment: I edited my response. I missed the part that you need to lookup the exact word you searched

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) and [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), I can see the `c_option` variable having its anticipated value in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener using the [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler).

Here is the demo, you can cross check the placement of the JSON Extractor (be aware of JMeter [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)) and other configuration values and compare it to yours.

[image]